# Why does `import torch`, without using any `torch` module, take up to 5 seconds?

Tags: python, torch, interpreter

I have realised that whenever I import `torch` in any of my python files, the import is lagging, i.e. takes up to 5 or 6 seconds, even though I am only printing hello world and not using any modules from `torch`. So, running this simple programme from my terminal takes around 5 seconds every time I run it:

```
import torch
print('hello world')
```

Could it be that the interpreter must find the torch module first or what could cause this lag? Also, running the script diretly from VS Code with the run button does not work, it says there is no module named `'torch'`, even though I have selected the right interpreter.

In VS Code, if I want to select an interpreter, Python 3.8.3 is the base, then I have Python 3.8.15 and my virtual environment with 3.11.4. I am working on a MacBook Pro (2019) with Sonoma14.0.

**EDIT:**

Whenever I run a python script from the terminal, I get a pop up from xcode saying, the Python3 command requires the command line developer tools, asking if I want to install it. I did already, but I get this pop-up every time.

Comment: You describe several problems, possibly related. I assume you want help with the one described in the title, and all the others are just context. You might want to clarify that — which problem do you want to solve? — typically a question should be specific and have just one answer.  Also, before "script diretly from VS Code" — what do you compare it with? Which environment is it that is slow (but works)?

Comment: Run `python -v -c "import torch"` to see all of the things that happen when you `import torch`...

Comment: @anatolyg Sorry, the title is also wrongly stated, I have just adjusted the title. But yes, I am mainly concerned why importing `torch` takes around 5 seconds and how to resolve this issue. I assume it has something to do with the path, which is why I mentioned the other issues as well. Regarding your question: I have `torch` only installed in the virtual environment. In VS Code I have selected this `venv` as the interpreter, but if I run the code from VS code direclty it says, `No module named 'torch'`.

Comment: @AKX is there anything I should look out for? The list is long, it's importing many different moduls, and half of the output is `destroy` some packages or `cleanup` ...

Comment: pytorch is a large module, importing it does take time, its not a specific problem with your setup. It is not something you can fix.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I totally understand and agree, I am just surprised that it takes now considerably longer than on my Ubuntu system. With "now" I mean, I had multiple versions of Python installed on my Mac and wanted to uninstall the older versions and just install Python 3.11, sort of do a clean-up. However, since I did that, I am encountering this issue, including the prompt from Xcode, that I have to install command line developer tools. So I am worried I messed up something by removing "too much".

Answer (score -1):

> Run `python -v -c "import torch"` to see all of the things that happen when you `import torch`...

–
AKX

Comment: how is this helping me? I see that many things happen, sure it's a large module to be imported. but I am working with `torch` for many years now, and never encountered this issue before, now all of a sudden it takes considerably longer to import

Comment: I never tried it but it looks like a way to answer your question. I think you have the highest chance to arrive to an answer, because there is not much other people can determine about your situation without guessing blindly. You can check each step which your system performs, and measure the time it takes. You can compare the steps with someone else who doesn't have the problem you have. In short, it's your problem; no one will solve it for you but someone will give you tools or advice to solve it on your own.